Connection attempt timeout when connecting to Postgres DB using IAM Authentication
"I have enabled IAM authentication on my database. When trying to connect using a token, I initially receive a 'connection attempt timeout' error. However, after several attempts (3-6 tries), the connection is eventually successful.
The following errors appear in the logs:

pam_authenticate failed: Permission denied
FATAL: canceling authentication due to timeout
HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable

Note:

I am using DBeaver to connect to the DB.

I am assuming a role in another account before generating the token.

I am using the same command to generate the token each time, and I have verified that the session is not expired.

What could be the issue that prevents the connection from succeeding on the first attempt?



I checked the policy and the db-user.
I checked the security group.
I checked IAM authentication is enabled

